# How to use mongoskin to serve query results to a page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, express, mongoose

I am using [mongoskin](https://github.com/guileen/node-mongoskin) nodejs plugin to talk to mongodb. But the problem is all mongoskin API methods are async and I am using a synchronous nodejs server (using express) to serve the webpages. How do I accomplish something like this:

```
server.get('/woofs', function(req, res) {
   var ret; 
   woofDb.find().toArray(function(err, i) {
     //do something with each i to construct ret
   });
   res.end(ret);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to not try to use a synchronous node.js server. It completely defeats the purpose of using node.js and the sooner you embrace that the more pleasant your node.js experience will be. That being said, the following code should get you pretty close to what you're trying to do.

```
server.get('/woofs', function(req, res) {
   woofDb.find().toArray(function(err, i) {
       var ret;
      //do something with each i to construct ret
       res.end(ret);
   });
});
```

Comment: What should I use then? Should I keep using mongoskin and change the way my server works OR keep using express and use some other mongo adaptor? Which is better? I personally love express more than mongoskin so what mongo adapter is synchronous that I can use with express - mongodb-native is not as nice and mongoose is not synchronous either...

Comment: The example in my answer is not synchronous. Express by default is non-blocking just like pretty much all the node.js libraries. There is no reason you can't use express and mongoskin.